# What happens when you change your team site name on sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

Our team site name is too long and makes it hard to save large file names in subfolders. A solution is to reduce the characters in the team site name.

- My question is how will this affect our users?
- We have all connected our Sharepoint site to our PC's via OneDrive.
  Will everyone need to restart?
- will the changes take place immediately?
- will this cause any errors?

Comment: what you mean by name change? are yout alking about Title or url of the site collection i.e sp.onmicrosoft.com/sites/abcccccccccccc to sp.onmicrosoft.com/sites/abc ?

Comment: Title of site collection

Answer (score 1):

If you change the title of the site collection, it will not cause any errors.

And after you change the title of the site collection, the title of site collection will change immediately.

If the site is connected to the PCs by OneDrive, there is no need to restart.